# Awesome WM: automatically display client across two monitors

Tags: awesome-wm

I have two monitors, and out the box AwesomeWM works exactly the way I like. However I would like to launch one particular app (avidemux) extra wide, so that it extends horizontally across *both* screens.

[desired: app across both screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTCkn.png)

I've tried to achieve this with:

```
 { rule = { class = "avidemux" }, properties = { floating = true },
    callback = function(c)
        c:geometry( { x = 0, y = 0, width = 5120, height = 1440 } )
    end
}
```

With this change, avidemux windows are indeed wide, but the window top-left corner is positioned way off-screen, and the window right border is flush to the right of my left monitor.

[actual: app on one screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asMgu.png)

I'm using awesomewm 3.5.6 (Ubuntu 16.04), use the 'nvidia' driver. My rc.lua is pretty standard, but calls xrandr early on to set the screens how I like:

xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 2560x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-0 --off

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: [Pastebin of rc.lua](http://pastebin.com/DbLYE84V)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send window to right monitor before applying geometry, something like

```
callback = function(c)
    c.screen = 2
    c:geometry( { x = 0, y = 0, width = 5120, height = 1440 } )
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. Putting c.screen before c:geometry has no effect. Putting it after causes new windows to appear on screen 2, but constrained to the dimensions of window 2.

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation, this works:

```
c:geometry( { x = SCREEN1_WIDTH, y = 0, width = SCREEN1_WIDTH + SCREEN2_WIDTH, height = SCREEN1_HEIGHT } )
```

In my case with two 2560x1440 screens:

```
c:geometry( { x = 2560, y = 0, width = 5120, height = 1440 } )
```

The solution does not generalize in any sane way, e.g. I cannot get a 100px right-screen overlap with this:

```
c:geometry( { x = 100, y = 0, width = 2660, height = 1440 } )
```

also, negative x and y's don't work.